# How to determine the admin users of a given machine on domain?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to programmatically determine the name of the users who are administrator on a given machine on a windows network. How can I do it?

I intend to use C# but if i need to use PInvoke to achieve this, that wouldn't be problem.

Comment: Is this a heterogeneous network of computers or all they all connected and authenticated through Active Directory?

Comment: This question has been answered multiple times in SO and other forums. The problem is background knowledge so you know what question to ask :-)

There is no guarantee on any given system that the group named 'adminstrators' actually has administration rights. It is just a label. You need to allow the software installer/administrator to select a group to be the administrators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Detect if user is in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899303/detect-if-user-is-in-a-group)